# C++ function to remove parenthesis from string doesn't catch them all

Tags: c++

I wrote a function in c++ to remove parenthesis from a string, but it doesn't always catch them all for some reason that I'm sure is really simple.

```
string sanitize(string word)
{
int i = 0;

while(i < word.size())
{
    if(word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')')
    {
        word.erase(i,1);
    }
    i++;
}
return word;
}
```

Sample result:

Input:  ((3)8)8)8)8))7

Output: (38888)7

Why is this?  I can get around the problem by calling the function on the output (so running the string through twice), but that is clearly not "good" programming.  Thanks!

Comment: A note to any future visitors: `word.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(word), std::end(word), [](char c) {return c == '(' || c == ')';}), std::end(word));` should just about do it.

Comment: @chris, that should be an _answer,_ not a comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I suppose so. I figured there were already good answers pertaining to the OP's code, but I thought I'd fill in the gap.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I completely missed the appendage to David's answer until right after I posted that. So it is there after all :p I guess I didn't look too hard after last time, when it wasn't there yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if(word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')')
{
    word.erase(i,1);
}
i++;
```

If you erase a parenthesis, the next character moves to the index previously occupied by the parenthesis, so it is not checked. Use an `else`.

```
if(word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')')
{
    word.erase(i,1);
} else {
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, and I knew it was something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
while(i < word.size())
{
    if(word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')')
    {
        word.erase(i,1);
    }
    i++;
}
```

When you remove an element the next element is moved to that location. If you want to test it, you will have to avoid incrementing the counter:

```
while (i < word.size()) {
   if (word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')' ) {
      word.erase(i,1);
   } else {
      ++i;
   }
}
```

That can also be done with iterators, but either option is bad. For each parenthesis in the string, all elements that are *after* it will be copied, which means that your function has quadratic complexity: `O(N^2)`. A much better solution is use the *erase-remove* idiom:

```
s.erase( std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                        [](char ch){ return ch==`(` || ch ==`)`; })
         s.end() );
```

If your compiler does not have support for lambdas you can implement the check as a function object (functor). This algorithm has linear complexity `O(N)` as the elements that are not removed are copied only once to the final location.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because your incrementing the index in all cases. You should only do that if you're not deleting the character, since the deletion shifts all the characters beyond that point back by one.

In other words, you'll have this problem wherever you have two or more consecutive characters to delete. Rather than deleting them both, it "collapses" the two into one.

Running it through your function twice will work on that particular input string but you'll still get into trouble with something like "((((pax))))" since the first call will collapse it to "((pax))" and the second will give you "(pax)".

One solution is to *not* advance the index when deleting a character:

```
std::string sanitize (std::string word) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < word.size()) {
        if(word[i] == '(' || word[i] == ')') {
            word.erase(i,1);
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return word;
}
```

However, I'd be using the facilities of the language a little more intelligently. C++ strings *already* have the capability to search for a selection of characters, one that's possibly far more optimised than a user loop. So you can use a much simpler approach:

```
std::string sanitize (std::string word) {
    int spos = 0;

    while ((spos = word.find_first_of ("()", spos)) != std::string::npos)
            word.erase (spos, 1);
    return word;
}
```

You can see this in action in the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string sanitize (std::string word) {
    int i = 0;

    while ((i = word.find_first_of ("()", i)) != std::string::npos)
            word.erase (i, 1);
    return word;
}

int main (void) {
    std::string s = "((3)8)8)8)8))7 ((((pax))))";
    s = sanitize (s);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
388887 pax
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use strtok and a temporary string?

```
string sanitize(string word)
{
int i = 0;
 string rVal;
 char * temp;
strtok(word.c_str(), "()"); //I make the assumption that your values should always start with a (
do
{
   temp = strtok(0, "()");
   if(temp == 0)
   {
       break;
   }
   else { rVal += temp;}
}while(1);

return rVal;
}
```

Comment: Viable is viable. Personally, I prefer working with char* over std::string, which most people find odd. Which, if we wanted to go with a pure C++ method, I'm sure there's a million ways to go about doing it.

-- Additionally, best part about programming: A million ways to get to home base.

Comment: Lets start with the fact that this doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, @MooingDuck, C++ has strtok, it's in the `cstring` header.

Comment: If I was going to give him everything, I would have just personal messaged him with the code. A (char *), or a dynamic_cast<> if people wish to go about it that way would solve. Or a complete other solution would have been devised if I were to solve the entire thing for him.

Granted, you are right. Versus reinventing the wheel I could have just repaired his function as-is.

Comment: The `c_str()` member function returns a `const char *`. Modifying the string, like this awful example, is undefined behavior. If you must use `strtok` you have to make your own copy of the string first.